# location.hash and history.replaceState

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate, html5-history

I have an issue with binding to window.hashchange. When calling `history.replaceState`, it triggers the 'hashchange' event unless a call has been made to `location.hash`. I am using Chrome 42, and jQuery to assist the binding. I have Sammy.js loaded (and I am actually trying to work out how Sammy would interpret the behaviour)

I am debugging in the console, and doing the following:

`$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) { alert('# change' + location.hash); });`

`history.replaceState({}, "", "#2")` --> **shows the alert**

`location.hash = "3"` --> shows the alert

`history.replaceState({}, "", "#4")` --> **does not show alert**

Is this a bug, or expected behaviour? I would have thought that replaceState either always, or never triggered the 'hashchange' event

Comment: I don't know about Chrome 42, but Chrome 51 does not fire a `hashchange` event on my end for `replaceState` in any case, and I don't think it's supposed to.

Comment: should you  use setInterval() function and save the corrent hash on hidden  input and verify it on set interval  if the input value is older than  hash on url is cause it changed, so  do  what  you have to do  and update the input.

Answer (score 9):

It is simple, you must fire `hashchange` native event in window after history.replaceState e.g. :

```js
history.replaceState(null, null, '#yourHash');
window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent('hashchange'));
```

Answer (score 8):

In my Chromium browser only the `location.hash = "3"` line triggers a `hashchange` event and it's not a "bug".

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) documentation:

> Note that `pushState()` never causes a `hashchange` event to be fired, even if the new URL differs from the old URL only in its hash.

And:

> `history.replaceState()` operates **exactly** like `history.pushState()` except that `replaceState()` modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.

Comment: In my browser, the first "replaceState" does fire the 'hashchange' event, which is what I think is the abnormal behaviour... it is possible that Sammy.js is somehow interfering though. I should run another test without Sammy loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Include the data with event.

```
const hash = "#/foo/bar"
history.pushState(null, '', hash);
window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent('hashchange', {
  newURL: window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + hash,
  oldURL: window.location.href,
}));
```